# Sound converter on Ubuntu Gnome offers no option for converting audios to m4a

Tags: aac, m4a, soundconverter

Can't seem to find anything missing for Sound converter on Ubuntu 18.04 for no longer offering to convert audios to m4a.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to install "ubuntu-restricted-extras" before proprietary codex such as m4a become available as a choice.

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (66).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  sqlite3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.